# How to loop query with given parameters in Birt Report

Tags: birt, spagobi, fiware-knowage

I Have made a report in birt.
The dataset of the report containing the query which contains many where conditions using a Startdate parameter.
I have made two parameters `Startdate` and `Enddate`. I want to loop that parameter from a `Startdate` parameter to `Enddate` parameter.

I want to run a single query with different parameter eveytime, Starting from Startdate till enddate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done through beforeOpen Script of the data Set.